# Visual glitch when pushing new page onto navigation page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using `Navigation.PushAsync` to add a new screen to a navigation stack. However, the animation has started acting glitchy...

[image]

Both screens are white but, during the transition, it goes a murky grey and you can see views from both pages sharing the same space.

Any ideas why this might have happened?

It seems to be coming and going. How odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a background color seems to have fixed it.